# Append variable in php for each loop

Tags: php

I have the following code which shows a tick and x in a table (the 4th td). I would like to count the number of ticks and x returned so that i can use them for a chart. I am not experienced at php at all so any help would be appreciated. I was thinking of declaring a variable outside the foreach statement and append it each time, but the code for the tick/x has thrown me off!

Thanks

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped" >
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Student Name</th>
                                        <th>Date Assigned</th>
                                        <th>Deadline</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php $ncmpt=0; $cmpt=0;
                                    if (isset($homework_assignment_track) && count($homework_assignment_track) > 0) {
                                        foreach ($homework_assignment_track as $key => $row) {
                                            ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><?= $row->student->name; ?></a></td>
                                                <td><?= date_format(new DateTime($row->assignment->created_at), 'd-M-Y'); ?></td>
                                                <td><?= $row->assignment->valid_date == '1' ? 'Open' : date_format(new DateTime($row->assignment->deadline), 'd-M-Y'); ?></td>
                                                <td><?= (($row->assignment->valid_date == '1') ? '<i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>' : ((isset($row->homeworkCompleteNotification->created_at) && $row->homeworkCompleteNotification->created_at < $row->assignment->deadline) ? '<i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>' : '<i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i>')); ?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center;">No Record Found!</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php
                                    } 
                                    ?>
                                </table>



enter code here
```

Comment: Are you asking how to assign a variable and increment it?

Comment: do you want to count how many `failed` values you got and how many `checked`?

Comment: Yes, this is what i want.

Comment: @Dorvalla. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
if (isset($homework_assignment_track) && count($homework_assignment_track) > 0) {
  $x=0;
  foreach ($homework_assignment_track as $key => $row) {
  ?>
  <tr>
      <td><?= $row->student->name; ?></a></td>
      <td><?= date_format(new DateTime($row->assignment->created_at), 'd-M-Y'); ?></td>
      <td><?= $row->assignment->valid_date == '1' ? 'Open' : date_format(new DateTime($row->assignment->deadline), 'd-M-Y'); ?></td>
      <td><?= (($row->assignment->valid_date == '1') ? '<i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>' : ((isset($row->homeworkCompleteNotification->created_at) && $row->homeworkCompleteNotification->created_at < $row->assignment->deadline) ? '<i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>' : '<i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i>')); ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}
foreach ($homework_assignment_track as $key => $row) {
if($row->assignment->valid_date == '1') x++;
}
```

And you can use the value of x as your wish

Comment: Would this simply not return the total number of records from the foreach loop? Whereas I am looking for the total ticks and x returned. The last td shows a tick (fa-check) or an x (fa-time). It is these that I want to count.

Comment: @Greenbird Can you update your above question with the whole block of foreach code

Comment: I updated, though not much was missing. You can see the foreach block loops and populates the table. I am not looking to count the total records outputted but as explained above, the tick/x as outputted in the last td.

Comment: You mean, depending on data, on the 4th td a tick is printed. And you want to count how many ticks are printed after a table is formed.

Comment: @Greenbird I have updated the code, try and let me know

Comment: No, this does not work. Firstly, it gives parse error with ';' and removing it simply outputs the value of x originally set, which is '0'. So the table now shows a tick and next to it '0'.

Comment: I have made some changes, now try that

Comment: This does not work either. x remains as 0 always. In any case, this is outside the original loop